# How do I use Heroku environment variable in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, environment-variables

I have a program that increments a number in a variable: the variable currently is saved in memory, but I realize that heroku cycles the worker randomly, and that would mean my variable in memory would be lost. So, I intend to turn it into an environment variable; but, I don't know how to use it in my code.

The variable in my python code: `cum_num = 98`.

How would this work if I made an exact `cum_num`, but as a heroku environment variable?

Comment: needs a bit more context, from what you have written, its not clear that environment variables are the way to go. do separate workers access this variable at the same time, or do you just want this variable to persist after your worker gets shut down and then restarted?

Comment: @DannyKong yes for the second part "do you just want this variable to persist after your worker gets shut down and then restarted? "

Comment: They're not _Heroku_ environment variables, they're just environment variables. Use them how you'd [use any environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-names-command-line-arguments-and-environment-variables), e.g via [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) or [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv).

Comment: "So, I intend to turn it into an environment variable"—that's not what environment variables are for. They're not to share state. (And environment variables are _environment_-specific. They'll be reset when your dyno restarts anyway, and they aren't shared between dynos.) Use an actual data persistence tool like a database, even an in-memory one if your use case supports that.